# Detecting changes between two pictures

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in python & image processing.I have the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5teL.jpg).

I would like to detect the changes between this picture and another one where the other one may be

- taken from a slightly different angle or the object is translated
- have different light conditions

and the changes may be

- a change in color in part of the object
- an extra or missing part

After various searches I thought about using ORB to detect the matching parts and remove them from the picture then use contour to extract and compare the difference.

But I cannot seem to find a way to remove the matching parts from the two images.

I am open for all suggestions / better way to approach the problem.

---

edit:
Sorry , forgot to mention that the color change could either be white or pink

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your image, it appears there are three dominant colors. If this is always the case the first thing that comes to mind is to apply a color K mean algorithm with three clusters, like explained [here](https://buzzrobot.com/dominant-colors-in-an-image-using-k-means-clustering-3c7af4622036).

The center color of each cluster would then give you information on the color of the tubes, and the size of each cluster (# of pixels belonging to that cluster) would give you if there are extra or missing parts.

[image]